# How to view the trace_id of the default trace files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, trace

Sql server automatically creates the default trace into multiple files. These can be seen in the LOGS directory of sql server installation path.

The sys.fn_trace_getinfo has a trace_id parameter which I'm not sure where I can find.

How to view the trace_id of the default trace files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Trace ID in the DMV [sys.traces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-traces-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-trace-getinfo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), other valid inputs are `NULL`, `0` or `DEFAULT`.

> Valid inputs are the ID number of a trace, NULL, 0, or DEFAULT. NULL,
> 0, and DEFAULT are equivalent values in this context. Specify NULL, 0,
> or DEFAULT to return information for all traces in the instance of SQL
> Server.

But the documentation also has a warning that `sys.fn_trace_getinfo` should no longer be used, and to use Extended events instead.

Comment: What is the extended events equivalent for this?